# How to install sass into your system (with or without ruby)

Tags: python, html, css, sass

I have a web application which is build in python html ans css, so I want to convert my css files into sass and not sure which option to opt for

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/install  
https://medium.com/@ricardozea/sass-for-beginners-the-friendliest-guide-about-how-to-install-use-sass-on-windows-22ff4a32c1f7  
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass

Answer (score 1):

To install sass

```
npm install -g sass
```

then, to convert scss to css

```
sass source/stylesheets/index.scss build/stylesheets/index.css
```

More info [here](https://sass-lang.com/install)

Comment: and how can we install with ruby .. Which one is better one to use . Which one is use where and why